# unique index across join?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Three Tables.

Event has many Races

Race has many Registrations

Registrations has a integer on it 'bib_number'

What I need is to ensure that bib number is unique to the Event.

The best solution I have is to denormalize event_id onto registrations... then I could just add a unique key to registrations:

```
UNIQUE KEY `index_bib_number_event_id` (`bib_number`, `event_id`)
```

....but I'd rather avoid that if possible

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `registrations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `race_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bib_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)

CREATE TABLE `races` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
}

CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is possible (which is why this is a comment not an answer) but have you tried creating a unique index on a view?

Comment: Bib number is unique to the event, and not to the race?

Comment: @Catcall, the OP wants to ensure that the Bib number is unique to the *whole* event, not *just* the race.

Comment: @MarkBannister: I know what he said. I'm questioning whether that's what he really meant.

Comment: @Catcall: Are you trying to ask "Is the Bib number unique to the race but *not* the event"? (You actually asked the opposite.)

Comment: @MarkBannister: Yes. My thinking and my writing were heading toward the same point from opposite directions.  I answered based on it being unique to the event.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work.  I'm sure you can fix up the syntax for MySQL.

I've omitted the autonumbers, because they can hide what's really going on. All tables are in at least 5NF, a fact you might overlook if you use autoincrementing numbers.

```
create table events (
  event_id integer primary key
);

create table races (
  event_id integer not null references events (event_id),
  race_id integer not null,
  primary key (event_id, race_id)
);

create table registrations (
  event_id integer not null,
  race_id integer not null,

  foreign key (event_id, race_id) 
    references races (event_id, race_id),

  registration_id integer not null,
  primary key (event_id, race_id, registration_id),

  bib_number integer not null,

  unique (event_id, bib_number)
);
```

Here's some sample data to play with.

```
-- Two events.
insert into events values (1);
insert into events values (2);

-- Three races in each event.
insert into races values (1,1);
insert into races values (1,2);
insert into races values (1,3);
insert into races values (2,1);
insert into races values (2,2);
insert into races values (2,3);

-- Some registrations.
insert into registrations values (1, 1, 1, 51);
insert into registrations values (1, 1, 2, 52);
insert into registrations values (1, 1, 3, 53);
insert into registrations values (1, 1, 4, 54);
insert into registrations values (1, 2, 1, 61);
insert into registrations values (1, 2, 2, 62);
insert into registrations values (1, 2, 3, 63);
insert into registrations values (1, 2, 4, 64);
insert into registrations values (1, 3, 1, 71);
insert into registrations values (1, 3, 2, 72);
insert into registrations values (1, 3, 3, 73);
insert into registrations values (1, 3, 4, 74);

-- These bib numbers were already used, but not in event 2.
insert into registrations values (2, 1, 1, 51);
insert into registrations values (2, 1, 2, 52);
insert into registrations values (2, 1, 3, 53);
insert into registrations values (2, 1, 4, 54);
```

Comment: `primary key (event_id, race_id, registration_id)` seems redundant. Either `(event_id, race_id)` or `(registration_id)` can be a primary key for the `registrations` table. It's the latter in the OP's schema, but, as you are adding the `event_id` column to the `registrations` table, a dedicated ID column may turn out totally unnecessary. What do you think?

Comment: @AndriyM: It's hard to say for sure, because we don't have any real data besides the bib number. Normalization, identification of candidate keys, functional dependencies--those all have to do with real attributes and real data, not with surrogate id numbers.  As it stands, {event_id, race_id} isn't sufficient to identify a row in registrations, but {event_id, race_id, bib_number} is.  (Also, you could add other real attributes to "events" in such a way that it's only in 2NF instead of in 5NF.)

Comment: Hm, you are right of course, and I'm wondering how I was able to come up with that a silly idea. I might have had something different in mind, however, if so, I can't remember now what it was. Perhaps I was thinking about `race_id` being redundant instead of `registration_id`, yet I'm not sure. In any event, sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score -1):

You see.. you already denormalize your `registration` table because `bib_number` doesn't depend on PK (id). So, you can feel free to move `event_id` to `registration` but i'd rather to take a look on db model once again and try to find out is it fine. May be you missed something during designing db.